# AWS API gateway: how to fix "internal server error"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function written in Python 3.6 and testing that from the lambda console works fine returning this as a response

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": {
    "bank": "my bank",
    "trust_name": "my trust",
    "start_time": "Wed 09 Oct 07:56AM",
    "end_time": "Wed 09 Oct 08:26AM",
    "cost": 111
  }
}
```

from the lambda function console I clicked add trigger then chose API Gateway once I had an API I created a resource and then a GET method inside that resource

However when I test my endpoint from API gateway I get this in the response body

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Comment: How do you test your lambda with what form of test event? Is that same form of api gateway event?

Comment: That's a good point! To test my lambda function I have this configuration {
  "query": ""
}  where would I need to add this in API gateway

Comment: You should test with a [real example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https.html) which have some complicated json event.

Comment: did you tried to develop the api from apigateway console

Comment: @NarendraChouhan I already  tried from within the console, I have "malformed lambda proxy response" so I believe it is something to do with how I am returning my data in the lambda function

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Chalice](https://realpython.com/aws-chalice-serverless-python/) a Python Serverless Microframework developed by AWS, enables you to quickly spin up and deploy a working serverless app that scales up and down on its own as required using AWS Lambda.

This deployed my lambda function and hooked it up to API gateway with no issues other than having to add any dependencies through lambda layers manually